# How to work with reserved CMA memory?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory, device-tree

I would like to allocate piece of physically contiguous reserved memory (in predefined physical addresses) for my device with DMA support.
As I see CMA has three options:
1. To reserve memory via kernel config file. 2. To reserve memory via kernel cmdline. 3. To reserve memory via device-tree memory node.
In the first case: size and number of areas could be reserved.

```
CONFIG_DMA_CMA=y
CONFIG_CMA_AREAS=7
CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES=8
```

So I could use:

```
start_cma_virt = dma_alloc_coherent(dev->cmadev, (size_t)size_cma, &start_cma_dma, GFP_KERNEL);
```

in my driver to allocate contiguous memory. I could use it max 7 times and it will be possible allocate up to 8M. But unfortunately

```
dma_contiguous_reserve(min(arm_dma_limit, arm_lowmem_limit));
```

from arch/arm/mm/init.c:

```
void __init arm_memblock_init(struct meminfo *mi,const struct machine_desc *mdesc)
```

it is impossible to set predefined physical addresses for contiguous allocation.
Of Course I could use kernel cmdline:

```
mem=cma=cmadevlabel=8M@32M cma_map=mydevname=cmadevlabel
//struct device *dev = cmadev->dev; /*dev->name is mydevname*/
```

After that dma_alloc_coherent() should alloc memory in physical memory area from 32M + 8M (0x2000000 + 0x800000) up to 0x27FFFFF.
But unfortunately I have problem with this solution. Maybe my cmdline has error?
Next one try was device tree implementation.

```
cmadev_region: mycma {
    /*no-map;*/ /*DMA coherent memory*/
    /*reusable;*/
    reg = <0x02000000 0x00100000>;      
};
```

And phandle in some node:

```
memory-region = <&cmadev_region>;
```

As I saw in kernel usual it should be used like:

```
of_find_node_by_name(); //find needed node
of_parse_phandle(); //resolve a phandle property to a device_node pointer
of_get_address(); //get DT __be32 physical addresses
of_translate_address(); //DT represent local (bus, device) addresses so translate it to CPU physical addresses 
request_mem_region(); //reserve IOMAP memory (cat /proc/iomem)
ioremap(); //alloc entry in page table for reserved memory and return kernel logical addresses.
```

But I want use DMA via (as I know only one external API function dma_alloc_coherent) dma_alloc_coherent() instead IO-MAP ioremap(). But how call

start_cma_virt = dma_alloc_coherent(dev->cmadev, (size_t)size_cma, &start_cma_dma, GFP_KERNEL);

associate memory from device-tree (reg = <0x02000000 0x00100000>;) to dev->cmadev ? In case with cmdline it is clear it has device name and addresses region.
Does reserved memory after call of_parse_phandle() automatically should be booked for your special driver (which parse DT). And next call dma_alloc_coherent will allocate dma area inside memory from cmadev_region: mycma?

Answer (score 4):

To use dma_alloc_coherent() on reserved memory node, you need to declare that area as dma_coherent. You can do some thing like:

In dt:

```
cmadev_region: mycma {
    compatible = "compatible-name"
    no-map;
    reg = <0x02000000 0x00100000>;      
};
```

In your driver:

```
struct device *cma_dev;

static int rmem_dma_device_init(struct reserved_mem *rmem, struct device *dev)
{
    int ret;

    if (!mem) {
        ret = dma_declare_coherent_memory(cma_dev, rmem->base, rmem->base,
                           rmem->size, DMA_MEMORY_EXCLUSIVE);
        if (ret) {
            pr_err("Error");
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void rmem_dma_device_release(struct reserved_mem *rmem,
                struct device *dev)
{
    if (dev)
        dev->dma_mem = NULL;
}

static const struct reserved_mem_ops rmem_dma_ops = {
    .device_init    = rmem_dma_device_init,
    .device_release = rmem_dma_device_release,
};

int __init cma_setup(struct reserved_mem *rmem)
{
    rmem->ops = &rmem_dma_ops;
    return 0;
}
RESERVEDMEM_OF_DECLARE(some-name, "compatible-name", cma_setup);
```

Now on this cma_dev you can perform dma_alloc_coherent and get memory.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).